# how to fetch multiple data simultaneously from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Fetch messages method

```
private void fetchMessages() {
    rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                    messagesList.add(messages);
                    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {



                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            });
}
```

Defining Ids

```
MessageSenderId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
MessageRecieverId = getIntent().getStringExtra("visit_user_id");
```

trying to make a basic chat app
Since only the senders id is called in rootref only the messages i send r being displayed in d recyclerview... im unable to receive messages because of this... how can i make it to retrieve recievers id and senders id also at the same time

Database strucutre

```
{
"Messages" : {
"+918105571584" : {
  "+919945342730" : {
    "-L58IPCLEeE21vH_-1Ry" : {
      "message" : "Hi",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1518427022478,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L58IU1VIHN0rHaUox3a" : {
      "message" : "Hello",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1518427042257,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L58IYN1GpHPdkWCY7Hn" : {
      "message" : "Hi",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1518427060021,
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
 },
"+919945342730" : {
  "+918105571584" : {
    "-L58IPCLEeE21vH_-1Ry" : {
      "message" : "Hi",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1518427022478,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L58IU1VIHN0rHaUox3a" : {
      "message" : "Hello",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1518427042257,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L58IYN1GpHPdkWCY7Hn" : {
      "message" : "Hi",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1518427060021,
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
}
},
"Users" : {
"+918105571584" : {
  "Email" : "",
  "Name" : "Akash",
  "Quote" : "",
  "Status" : ""
},
"+919945342730" : {
  "Email" : "",
  "Name" : "Sav",
  "Quote" : "",
  "Status" : ""
}
}
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code now?

Comment: i can send messages and it stores in the database and retrieves to d listview as well.... but now able to retrieve the messages sent by the other person which is stored in d database

Comment: Give me a concrete example.

Comment: See... im person X n im texting Y... all the messages i send r getting stored in database n showing in my listview.... all the messages Y sends is storing in database and storing in listview... but X is not able to see d messages sent by Y and Y is not able to See d messages sent by X... like im not able to retrieve the messages sent by the other person

Answer (score 0):

According to your last comment, I understand that you can display only the messages that correpond to a single user. A user can see only his messages butd not other user messages. To solve this, you need to create `chat rooms`, in which every user can add messages that can be seen by all chat room members.

So for that, you need to change your database structure. You cannot achieve this, using the actual database.

Comment: Ok how should i change the database to

Comment: As I said, by addning chat rooms. You need to creare a new node named `chatRooms`. So don't add the messages beneath each user, add those messaged beneath a chat room, where all the users that correspond to that chat room cand send and read messages.

Comment: but i want a one to one application so tried this... btw have any idea whats wrong in my code?

Comment: according to me... while retrieving rootref. etc etc... im only retrieving the messages sent by me... that is first senders id whch is my id... so hw can i chang tht to first recievers id

Comment: like i want tht fetch messages method to retrieve both of... first senders ids messages and first recievers ids messages... i guess tht will solve the problm

Comment: So this the only way in which you can solve this, by adding chat rooms in which a user cand send messages to another user. Your code is not wrong but is not for what you want to achieve. Using the actual database structure, won't help you. So your solution is not for what you need.